# Pandas - Handle NaN in Pivot Table with Categorical

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, categorical-data, fillna

I'm creating multiple pivot tables using a `Categorical` dtype then merging them into one big pivot table / dataframe.

However, in some cases I get `NaN` when I perform the merge, and when I try to `fillna(0)`, I get the following error: `ValueError: fill value must be in categories`

```
pv1 = pd.PivotTable(df, index='Category', values='Sales', aggfunc='sum')    
pv2 = pd.PivotTable(df, index='Category', values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum')    
chart = pv1.merge(pv2, on='Category', how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Actual Output:

```
 Category   Sales  Quantity
 Boxes      100    NaN
 Staples    20     10
 Paper      NaN    20
```

Desired Output:

```
 Category   Sales  Quantity
 Boxes      100    0
 Staples    20     10
 Paper      0      20
```

Comment: have you tried `fillna` on the columns individually?

Comment: @SuperStew I haven't, but that might be the trick. I guess doing `df.fillna(0)` will try to fill the entire dataframe, not just `Sales` and `Quantity`

Comment: `df[['Sales','Quantity']].fillna(0)`. You just indicate the columns

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do this was to define the columns I want to do the `fillna()` on, then perform it only on those columns (basically exclude the `categorical` column.

`fill_cols = ['Sales','Quantity']
df[fill_cols] = df[fill_cols].fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using `fillna` on the final output instead of in middle steps. This works perfectly:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]: 
  Category  Sales  Quantity
0    Boxes  100.0       NaN
1  Staples   20.0      10.0
2    Paper    NaN      20.0

In [122]: df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

In [123]: df
Out[123]: 
  Category  Sales  Quantity
0    Boxes  100.0       0.0
1  Staples   20.0      10.0
2    Paper    0.0      20.0
```

Comment: I still wasn't able to get this to work. Was your `Category` a `categorical` dtype?